# A geometric property of divergence (statistics)

Tags: calculus, statistics, differential-geometry, partial-derivative, information-geometry

I am reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)) wikipedia article about Divergence in statistics and I am a bit confused about the paragraph *Geometrical Properties*.

In particular I can't understand the following
$$
D[\partial_i \partial_j|| \, \cdot \,] = -D[\partial_i || \partial_j].
$$
It probably boils down to some basic calculus lemma, but I can't see it right now.

Any help would be very appreciated!